# Deleting parent tags without deleting children with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Sample code to remake:

```
       <div class="mrd3w m6et0 _2d49e_1O4vF"> 
        <div class="p1td4 pw4go p513t al2kje m10qy mij5n"> 
         <div class="_2d49e_2tor6" style="max-width:871px;max-height:552px"> 
          <div class="ptv8j2" style="padding-top:calc(100% * 552 / 871)">
           <img alt="alt" class="_2d49e_3B1Cq pt94f9 pt1itw ptux49 w1eai _2d49e_32cUf lazyloaded" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 560px, (min-width: 992px) 50vw, 100vw" src="https://somelink.com 871w" width="871px">
          </div> 
         </div> 
        </div> 
       </div>
```

I have already deleted some usless links and imports from this html and this is my last problem. Classes of divs are random and there are a lot of them.

I need to get simple clean code like this:

```
<div>
  <img alt="alt" src="https://somelink.com">
</div>
```

I am creating xml file from databse, and description of each product is a mess that needs to be as clean as possible. Whole description is in database as a value with all this mess iports and tags. I am using Jsoup to remake this description, but have no clue how to delete parents without deleting children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires two steps:

1. To clean unwanted tags and attributes use `Whitelist` and `Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist)`
2. To remove parent you can use `element.unwrap()`. To remove repeating parents we can move up using a loop and remove them if they are the same.

That's the code to do this:

```
public class JsoupIssue61137870 {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        String html = "  <div class=\"mrd3w m6et0 _2d49e_1O4vF\"> \n"
                + "        <div class=\"p1td4 pw4go p513t al2kje m10qy mij5n\"> \n"
                + "         <div class=\"_2d49e_2tor6\" style=\"max-width:871px;max-height:552px\"> \n"
                + "          <div class=\"ptv8j2\" style=\"padding-top:calc(100% * 552 / 871)\">\n"
                + "           <img alt=\"alt\" class=\"_2d49e_3B1Cq pt94f9 pt1itw ptux49 w1eai _2d49e_32cUf lazyloaded\" sizes=\"(min-width: 1200px) 560px, (min-width: 992px) 50vw, 100vw\" src=\"https://somelink.com 871w\" width=\"871px\">\n"
                + "          </div> \n" + "         </div> \n" + "        </div> \n" + "       </div> ";

        Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
        whitelist.addTags("div", "img");
        whitelist.addAttributes("img", "src");
        String cleanHTML = Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist);
        System.out.println(cleanHTML);

        String result = removeRepeatingTags(cleanHTML);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static String removeRepeatingTags(String html) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element img = doc.selectFirst("img");
        Element parent = img.parent();
        while (parent.tagName().equals(parent.parent().tagName())) {
            parent.unwrap();
            parent = img.parent();
        }
        return doc.toString();
    }
}
```

The ouput of the first part is:

```
<div> 
 <div> 
  <div> 
   <div> 
    <img alt="alt" src="https://somelink.com 871w"> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

and the output after second part is:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>    
    <img alt="alt" src="https://somelink.com 871w">  
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Jsoup will add `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags. To avoid this instead of

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

use

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

and the output will be exactly what you expect:

```
<div>    
 <img alt="alt" src="https://somelink.com 871w">    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After some time i got response that those img tags are not welcome in my xml so i used only whitelist and clean method. Above solution is really nice and it will be helpful in future.